# oracle sql - query to find special chars

Tags: sql, database, oracle, special-characters

Is there any SQL SELECT query that can be done in oracle to detect ascii characters such as LF, CR in fields? Basically any characters people have known to cause trouble in a oracle db environment in terms of breaking jobs/procedures.etc

I doubt this would work: - happy to use regex if possible

```
select * from table
where column like '%chr(13)%'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from table
where regexp_like(column, '(' || chr(13) || '|' || chr(10) || ')')
```

The regex used here is a form of `(a|b|c)` which matches the string if it contains `a OR b OR c`

Comment: On the off-chance you're running Oracle on z/os, you'll need to update the LF chr(10) to chr(37)